# Grouping class methods using dot notation in Python

Tags: python, oop

I've found many questions on StackOverflow that come close to solving my problem but none that quite do it. I have a class in Python and I would like to split its methods up so that I can use the class in the following way:

```
my_greeter = Greeter(name='Bob')
my_greeter.sayHello()
#> "Hello Bob"
my_greeter.international.sayHola()
#> "Hola Bob"
```

I'm not quite sure how to structure my files and their contents to achieve this. Could someone please give an example?

Note: An example of this behaviour in the wild is `pandas.Series.str.contains()` although the source code was too dense for me to pick apart how they did this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of Fluent API design, which uses method chaining in it's core. The implementation idea of this in Python is to return the instance from each method after doing what they are supposed to do.

Here is a naive example:

```
In [1]: class Fluent: 
   ...:     def __init__(self, num): 
   ...:         self.num = num 
   ...:     def add_two(self): 
   ...:         self.num += 2 
   ...:         return self  # this allows us for chaining
   ...:     def result(self): 
   ...:         return self.num 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [2]: f = Fluent(10)                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [3]: f.add_two().result()                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[3]: 12
```

You can make `add_two` a `property` to avoid the method call, and refer as an attribute:

```
f.add_two.result()
```

---

**Edit:** Example with `property`:

```
In [4]: class Fluent: 
   ...:     def __init__(self, num): 
   ...:         self.num = num
   ...:     @property
   ...:     def add_two(self): 
   ...:         self.num += 2 
   ...:         return self  # this allows us for chaining
   ...:     def result(self): 
   ...:         return self.num 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [5]: f = Fluent(10)                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [6]: f.add_two.result()                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[6]: 12
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to use properties to achieve this? I have used properties before but not for that purpose. It would be very helpful if you could use the example I used in my question.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after. Thank you

Comment: @TimHargreaves Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this while looking for a way to group methods. The accepted answer (fluent design) is great for *chaining* methods - where each `.method` is doing something - but I found a simpler option for simply grouping things together for organisational reasons:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.property1 = "foo"
        self.property2 = "bar"

        self.group1 = SimpleNamespace()
        self.group1.property3 = 1.23
        self.group1.property4 = 4.56
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this would be to import a module named `international` into your so called `Greeter` class. Then, you could do things as normal and put your methods under the `international` namespace into a different file. In your case:

```
# main.py
class Greeter:
    import international # To import the international file's contents into the class
    def __init__(self, name="someone"):
        self.name = name
    def sayHello(self):
        print(f"Hello {self.name}")
```

And the international file:

```
# international.py
def sayHola(self):
    print(f"Hola {self.name}")
```

Some notes:

- **Always** add `self` as the **first argument** in every method you define in `international.py`
- When you import the files into a class when the method is run the function **automatically** has `self` passed to it
- If you need helper functions that you do not want to be used by the user I would recommend you put them in a **different file** (and import them inside the method)