# Access previous dataframe during pandas method chaining

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, method-chaining

[Method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) is a known way to improve code readability and often referred to as a Fluent API [[1](https://florianeinfalt.de/posts/fluent-interfaces-in-python/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58670816/3991125)]. Pandas does support this approach as multiple method calls can be chained like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [5, np.nan, 7, 8], 'col3': [9, 10, 11, np.nan], 'col4': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = (
    pd
    .DataFrame(d)
    .set_index('col1')
    .drop(labels='col3', axis=1)
)

print(df)
```

How could I use method chaining if I need to access attributes of the DataFrame returned from the previous function call? To be specific, I need to call [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) on a column subset. As the DataFrame is generated from [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the exact column names are not known a priori. Therefore, I am currently using a two-step approach like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d_1 = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [5, np.nan, 7, 8], 'col3': [9, 10, 11, np.nan], 'col4': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}
d_2 = {'col10': [10, 20, 30, 40], 'col20': [50, np.nan, 70, 80], 'col30': [90, 100, 110, np.nan]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(d_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(d_2)

df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)
print(df)

dropped = df.dropna(how='any', subset=[c for c in df.columns if c != 'col4'])
print(dropped)
```

Is there a more elegant way based on method chaining? [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) can certainly be chained, but I did not find a way to access the column names of the DataFrame resulting from the previous [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). I image something like

```
# pseudo-code
dropped = (
    pd
    .concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)
    .dropna(how='any', subset=<access columns of dataframe returned from previous concat and ignore desired column>)
)
print(dropped)
```

but did not find a solution. Memory-efficiency could be improved by using [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with the `inplace=True` option to re-assign the variable in-place. However, readability with respect to method chaining remains unimproved.

Comment: use `pipe` to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
dropped = (
    pd
    .concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)
    .pipe(lambda d: d.dropna(how='any',
                             subset=[c for c in d.columns if c != 'col4']))
)
```

output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col10  col20  col30
0     1   5.0   9.0   NaN     10   50.0   90.0
2     3   7.0  11.0   NaN     30   70.0  110.0
```

*NB. alternative syntax for the `dropna`:*

```
lambda d: d.dropna(how='any', subset=d.columns.difference(['col4']))
```